# Jackson abstract class deserialization based on parameter value

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to deserialize the following JSON string:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "id": "id",
    "requirements": [
        {
            "requirement_type": "hard", // 'soft' or 'hard'
            "parameters": {
                "first": "value_1",
                "second": "value_2",
                "third": "value_3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Into the next DTOs:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class OwnObject {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private List<Requirement> requirement;

    // getters & setters
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public abstract class Requirement {
    private String requirement_type;
    private List<Parameter> parameters;

    // getters & setters
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class SoftRequirement {
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class HardRequirement {
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public abstract class Parameter {
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class SoftParameter {
    private String first;

    // getter & setter
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class HardParameter {
    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String third;

    // getters & setters
}
```

The mapping should be done based on the 'requirement_type' attribute, like:
If 'soft' then SoftRequirement and SoftParameter inside in that.
If 'hard' then HardRequirement and HardParameter inside in that.

Tried to handle this with this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "requirement_type")
@JsonSubTypes( {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SoftRequirement.class, name = "soft"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = HardRequirement.class, name = "hard")
} )
```

and

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "requirement_type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes( {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SoftParameter.class, name = "soft"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = HardParameter.class, name = "hard")
} )
```

At upper level (Requirement) it realize the type but not filling up 'requirement_type' in the subclass.
At lower level (Parameter) it is failing because it does not find the 'requirement_type' from the upper level.

Comment: Just drop your JSON to [here](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and check the generated java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the JSON is the right representation of your data: in the JSON the *parameters* field is an object instance, in your implementation is a List.

As stated [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXTERNAL_PROPERTY), `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` can only be used for properties.

So, you have to move all annotation from `Parameter` class to property `parameters` or `setParameters(...)` method in `Requirement` class.

This `Requirement` implementation will allow Jackson to correctly deserialize a single parameter object:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "requirement_type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes( {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SoftRequirement.class, name = "soft"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = HardRequirement.class, name = "hard")
} )
public abstract class Requirement {
    private String requirement_type;
    private Parameter parameters;

    public String getRequirement_type() {
        return this.requirement_type;
    }

    public void setRequirement_type(String requirement_type) {
        this.requirement_type = requirement_type;
    }

    public Parameter getParameters() {
        return this.parameters;
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "requirement_type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes( {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SoftParameter.class, name = "soft"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = HardParameter.class, name = "hard")
    } )
    public void setParameters(Parameter parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```